# Function pointer not returning a value

Tags: c, function-pointers

We just learnt in school about function pointers in C and i wanted to try them out in a test program. The idea is obviously pretty simple. However, when i try to use `result = (*funcPtr)();` i get an `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` exception but i can't tell what i did wrong. Any ideas on what i'm missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun1();
int fun2();

int (*funcPtr)(void);

int fun1() {
  return 1;
}

int fun2() {
  return 2;
}

int main(void) {
  int input,result = 0;
  scanf("%d",input);
  if(input == 1) {
    funcPtr = &fun1;
  } else if(input == 2) {
    funcPtr = &fun2;
  }
  result = (*funcPtr)();
  printf("%d\n",result);
}
```

Comment: It's problem with `scanf` (`scanf("%d",input);`)  not with function pointer. You are missing`&`.

Comment: Don't forget to handle the case where `input` is neither `1` nor `2`.

Comment: You might want to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially how to use a debugger to catch crashes as they happen to locate where in your code the problem is.

Comment: Hint: `scanf()`

Comment: You should really include `(void)` in place of `()` in the function declarations and definitions.  There _is_ a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a `&` before input in the `scanf`. Therefore `scanf` writes not to the address of the `input` variable, but to its value (and the variable is uninitialized a this point).

Change that line to:

```
scanf("%d", &input);
```

to pass a pointer to `input` to `scanf` and not the value of `input`.

And as already pointed out by other users, do not forget to handle inputs other than `1` and `2`. Otherwise you will call your uninitialized `funcPtr` variable, which most likly results in a Segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you, you and the others who commented pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: i should probably mention that `input` will actually be garbage data, *not* `0`.

Comment: Thank you @Tau, you are right. I have updated my answer